# SQL cummulative sum and date query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new when working with MySQL I've got the following problem:

I'm triyng to perform a query with these conditions:

> Given a posts table that contains a created_at timestamp column write
> a query that returns date (without time component), a number of posts
> for a given date and a running (cumulative) total number of posts up
> until a given date. The resulting set should be ordered
> chronologically by date.

Desired output:

```
date       | count | total
-----------+-------+-------
2017-01-26 |    20 |    20
2017-01-27 |    17 |    37
2017-01-28 |     7 |    44
2017-01-29 |     8 |    52
...
```

I have tried but i get an error:

> No rows returned

This is what I have got:

```
set @cumsum:=0
select date(created_at) as 'date',count(date),(@cumsum=@cumsum+date) as total from posts
order by 'date'
group by 'date','count','total'
```

Sample data:

```
id  created_at  title
1   2017-12-25 04:35:08 +0000   Quos ut cupiditate quis.
2   2017-12-25 18:56:42 +0000   Exercitationem sunt ab modi facilis qui mollitia excepturi.
3   2017-12-25 10:31:08 +0000   Ex consectetur odit quasi.
4   2017-12-25 16:31:20 +0000   Reiciendis similique officiis dolorum blanditiis voluptatem veritatis cum.
5   2017-12-25 15:06:42 +0000   Explicabo ab et enim voluptatem id sunt eius nihil.
6   2017-12-25 15:58:27 +0000   Reiciendis ut et consequatur rerum accusamus architecto ea.
7   2017-12-25 04:09:35 +0000   Doloremque odio dolore aperiam illo.
```

Comment: Why do you have `ORDER BY` ***before*** `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Please include sample table data

Comment: Also `date` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: @PM77-1 yep you are right I was using date as a column name, I corrected this. As I mentiond I just started using SQL sorry for my mistakes. And I have used 'order by' and 'group by' beacuse I'm supposed to return values order by date and as far as I know when using an operator such as count,sum, etc it is nessesary to include a group by. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have added a sample data. Thanks in advanced for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to get the date part of the date time correctly using `CAST AS DATE`.
- Don't group by all of these columns, you need to group by the date part only and count *.
- You need to get the anchor query first, the date, and the count for each date value.
- Then, use the same raking technique that you used to get the cumulative count.

Something like this:

```
SET @total:=0;
SELECT
   t.`Date`,
   t.Total,
   (@total := @total + t.Total) AS CummlativeTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT
       CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS `Date`,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM  posts
    WHERE  created_at <= '2017-01-28'
    GROUP  BY CAST(created_at AS DATE)
    ORDER  BY CAST(created_at AS DATE)
) AS t;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c822bb7/2)**:

```
|       Date | Total | CummlativeTotal |
|------------|-------|-----------------|
| 2017-12-25 |     3 |               3 |
| 2017-12-26 |     2 |               5 |
| 2017-12-27 |     2 |               7 |
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of zero results when running. But this is a good stating point.